# Better way of exporting the output in columns rather than rows using Export-Csv method in PowerShell for file hash comparison in Excel side by side

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have two folders (Fold1 and Fold2) with a lots of files in different formats (.doc, .pdf, .xml, .html) in them, and total number of items (files) may vary in each folder.  I am trying to compare the MD5 checksums for each file present in both the folders and for the files that are extra in either folders just list their checksums, so that I can copy/check those files later.

This is where I have reached:

```
$path1 = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Fold1"
$path2 = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Fold2"

$Data1 = dir "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Fold1" -Recurse |
         Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} |
         Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5  |
         select @{n='Hash';e={$_.Hash}}, @{n='File';e={Split-Path $_.Path -Leaf}}

$Data2 = dir "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Fold2" -Recurse |
         Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer} |
         Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5  |
         select @{n='Hash';e={$_.Hash}}, @{n='File';e={Split-Path $_.Path -Leaf}}

$Full = foreach ($d in $Data1) {
    $d | Select-Object Hash, File,@{n="Hash2";e={
        ($Data2 | Where-Object File -eq $d.File).Hash
    }}
}

$Full | Export-Csv .\report.csv
```

This gives output like this:

[image: Output Screenshot 1]

**Problem 1:**

Since I am using  `Where-Object File -eq $d.File`, so just in case if Folder 2 has one extra file than Folder 1, in such scenario it won't capture the extra file and the comparison goes wrong because I need to capture all the items regardless. To escape this I tried adding `.Count`,  which looks like this:

```
$Data1Count = (Get-ChildItem -File -Path $path1).Count
$Data2Count = (Get-ChildItem -File -Path $path2).Count

if ($Data1Count -gt $Data2Count) {
    $Full = foreach ($d in $Data1) {
        $d | Select-Object Hash,File,@{n="Hash2";e={
            ($Data2 | Where-Object File -eq $d.File).Hash
        }}
    }
    $Full
} elseif ($Data2Count -gt $Data1Count) {
    $Full = foreach ($d in $Data2) {
        $d | Select-Object Hash,File,@{n="Hash2";e={
            ($Data1 | Where-Object File -eq $d.File).Hash
        }}
    }
    $Full
} else {
    $Full = foreach ($d in $Data1) {
        $d | Select-Object Hash,File,@{n="Hash2";e={
            ($Data2 | Where-Object File -eq $d.File).Hash
        }}
    }
    $Full
}
```

**Problem 2:**

This method lists all the items (files) from one of the folders (Folder1 or Folder2) whichever has higher file counts, but it still does not list the extra files in the other folder. Just to show you, here is the directory structure:

[image: Directories Screenshot]

and this is the output (since number of files in Folder 2 is > Folder 1):

[image: Output Screenshot 2]

What I am trying to achieve is something like the following as the output of comparison, which lists all the matching files as well as extra files in either folders:

[image: Screenshot of Excel Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't how you'd handle something like this in PowerShell. The appropriate way of tackling this would be enumerating the files like you do in your first code sample, and then compare the lists with `Compare-Object`:

```bsh
Compare-Object $Data1 $Data2 -Property Hash -IncludeEqual -PassThru
```

which would give you output like this:

```
Hash                             File   SideIndicator
----                             ----   -------------
1DA53AC45042DB9413D1A6F055F7C5BA a.docx ==
2E9D15DF495521763D6CD5090B7DEF48 b.pdf  ==
8DA3E12E4908F49055BD679D68848D5A c.pdf  =>
6F0D8230A93276D335CE656CEB54B764 d.doc  <=
```

You can then use the side indicator for transforming the data like this:

```bsh
Compare-Object $Data1 $Data2 -IncludeEqual -Property Hash -PassThru |
    Select-Object @{n='Hash';e={if ($_.SideIndicator -ne '=>') {$_.Hash}}},
        @{n='File';e={if ($_.SideIndicator -ne '=>') {$_.File}}},
        @{n='Hash2';e={if ($_.SideIndicator -ne '<=') {$_.Hash}}},
        @{n='File2';e={if ($_.SideIndicator -ne '<=') {$_.File}}}
```

which would produce output like this:

```
Hash                             File   Hash2                            File2
----                             ----   -----                            -----
1DA53AC45042DB9413D1A6F055F7C5BA a.docx 1DA53AC45042DB9413D1A6F055F7C5BA a.docx
2E9D15DF495521763D6CD5090B7DEF48 b.pdf  2E9D15DF495521763D6CD5090B7DEF48 b.pdf
                                        8DA3E12E4908F49055BD679D68848D5A c.pdf
6F0D8230A93276D335CE656CEB54B764 d.doc
```

or transform the data like this:

```bsh
Compare-Object $Data1 $Data2 -IncludeEqual -Property Hash -PassThru |
    Select-Object Hash, File,
        @{n=$path1;e={if ($_.SideIndicator -ne '=>') {'X'}}},
        @{n=$path2;e={if ($_.SideIndicator -ne '<=') {'X'}}}
```

which would give a result like this:

```
Hash                             File   C:\...\Fold1 C:\...\Fold2
----                             ----   ------------ ------------
1DA53AC45042DB9413D1A6F055F7C5BA a.docx X            X
2E9D15DF495521763D6CD5090B7DEF48 b.pdf  X            X
8DA3E12E4908F49055BD679D68848D5A c.pdf               X
6F0D8230A93276D335CE656CEB54B764 d.doc  X
```

Then export that output to a CSV via `Export-Csv`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Great explanation.The second method that you suggested is way better and creative. Thanks a lot